# how to Call the Parent Node in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna Access To each Html Dynamic Control as Follow and each control has Id Ref1_ and Ref2_ :

```
$('[id^="Ref1_"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        var Temp = $(this).val() + ":" +$(this).parent().find("Ref2_").attr('id').split('_')[1]; 
        Data += Sp + $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1] + ":" + $(this).val();
        Sp = ',';
    }
});
```

I Wanna Combine Each Value dynamic Control , but Find dont Work

C# Code :

```
        HtmlTableRow r = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell CRef1 = new HtmlTableCell(); 
        HtmlTableCell CRef2 = new HtmlTableCell();
        HtmlInputText Ref1 = new HtmlInputText();
        Ref1.ID = "Ref1_" + iSrl;
        Ref1.Attributes.Add("dir", "ltr");
        HtmlInputText ref2 = new HtmlInputText();
        ref2.ID = "Ref2_" + iMSrl;
        ref2.Attributes.Add("dir", "ltr");
        CRef1.Controls.Add(Ref1);
        CRef2.Controls.Add(ref2);
        r.Controls.Add(CRef1);
        r.Controls.Add(CRef2);
        this.Table.Controls.Add(r);
```

Comment: How us your html code. else it kinda hard for us to tell you where the error is

Comment: Please include your current HTML which refers to `Ref1_` & `Ref2_`

Comment: In your explanation, you say the controls have id `Ref_1` or `Ref_2` but your jquery its  `Ref1_`.

Comment: Controls Are Created Dynamically in C# Code

Comment: @bernova Without your html code  then we cant really help you

Comment: Yes , I Edit it

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: Html are Created in RunTime Dynamically

Comment: @bernova you can get that HTML from source as well from browser

Comment: @bernova How its created don't matter, if you can show us the HTML then we cant help you.

Comment: update in your question instead of commenting code

Comment: I Update My Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var Data='', Sp='';
$('[id^="Ref1"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        
        //console.log($(this).attr("id")+ " : " + $(this).val() + " - Ref2" + $(this).parent().parent().find('[id^="Ref2"]').val());
        
        var Temp = $(this).val() + ":" + $(this).parent().parent().find('[id^="Ref2"]').attr('id').split('_')[1]; 
        Data += Sp + $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1]+ " : " + $(this).val() + "^" + $(this).parent().parent().find('[id^="Ref2"]').val();
        Sp = ',';
    }
});

    console.log(Data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Table">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input name="Ref1_1330" type="text" id="Ref1_1330" dir="ltr" 
     value="2342" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="Ref2_1330" type="text" id="Ref2_1330" dir="ltr" 
     value="23342" />
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
      <td><input name="Ref1_1474" type="text" id="Ref1_1474"   dir="ltr" value='657'/>
     </td>
      <td><input name="Ref2_1474" type="text" id="Ref2_1474" dir="ltr" value='957'  />
       </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

you can try this code

Comment: excuse me , but have Error : Undefined

Comment: for which variable?

Comment: $(this).closest('[id^="Ref2_"]')

Comment: your ids are just like this?

Comment: can u please copy your HTML portion from browser source right click and view source copy the html which is required for your question and update your question

Comment: @bernova please check i think you need something like this i have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
`
 <table id="Table">
    <td>
    <input name="Ref1_1330" type="text" id="Ref1_1330" dir="ltr" 
     value="2342" /></td>
    <td>
    <input name="Ref2_1330" type="text" id="Ref2_1330" dir="ltr" 
     value="23342" />
     </td>
    </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td><input name="Ref1_1474" type="text" id="Ref1_1474"   dir="ltr" />
     </td>
      <td><input name="Ref2_1474" type="text" id="Ref2_1474" dir="ltr"   />
       </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
 `
```

Comment: A Part of Dynamically table

Comment: @PrateikDarji Thanks But I Wanna Follow Result: 1330:2342^23342,1474:657^897